# php count function not working with textbox array

Tags: php

I want to count the number of textbox arrays that appeared in one page in the next page.
In the first page I put the textbox arrays as

```
echo "< input name=t1 [] type=hidden value=$row[ad_id] />";
```

Here 25 textbox arrays appeared.

In the next page I am accessing it as

```
$AID = $_POST['t1'];

$limit = count($t1);
```

The `$limit` variable is showing the value as 0, but in the first page 25 textbox arrays appeared. What is the problem?

Comment: Shouldnt it be `$limit = count($_POST['t1']);` or `$limit = count($AID);`?

Comment: Does the form's method post to the page you're trying to count the textboxes ?

Comment: Where do you set `$t1`?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this since `$_POST['t1']` is an array. You should get the right result:

```
$AID = $_POST['t1'];
$limit = count($AID);
```

Answer (score 0):

input name should be like `t1[]` instead of `t1 []`

```
echo "< input name='t1[]' type='hidden' value='".$row[ad_id]."' />";

if(isset($_POST['t1'])){      
     $AID = $_POST['t1'];
     echo $limit = count($AID);
}
```